# passing password to Java program from non-interactive Windows command line

Tags: c#, java, windows, command-line

I'm trying to call a Java program (that I don't own) from the Windows command line. It prompts for a password, which works fine when I do it interactively. However, I am trying to make this work non-interactively.

I have tried to do:

1. `echo mypassword|callJavaProgram.bat`. That resulted in a "password is empty" error.
2. Also I tried to use C# Process.Start and redirecting Standard Input, but that wasn't successful either.

My suspicion is that the Java program is using Console.ReadPassword, which does not use Standard Input and requires an interactive console. I'm looking for any solution for Windows.

Comment: `AutoIt` may work for you.